# Find the error between $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ and the Taylor Polynomial $T_2(x)$ at $a=100$ on the interval $[90,110]$

Tags: taylor-expansion

Find the error between $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ and the Taylor Series $T_2(x)$ at $a=100$ on the interval $[90,110]$

I found $T_2(x) = 10 + \frac{1}{20}(x-100)-\frac{1}{500}(x-100)^2$

For the error, I have that:

$|\sqrt{x} - T_2(x) | = \frac{f^{'''}(c)}{3!}|x-10|^{3} $ $\leq$ $\frac{sup_{c \in [90, 110]}f^{'''}(c)}{3!}|x-100|^3$

Since $f^{'''}(x)$ is decreasing, for $sup_{c \in [90, 110]}$, $c = 90$

once I plug this in above, I am not sure how to solve for the error.

Comment: @Moo so since I found the error is maximized at 90, do I plug that in for c and x?

Comment: The error is just $\max(|T_2(x)-\sqrt x|)$ over the range.  You can just maximize that.  The maximum is certainly at one of the end points.

Comment: @RossMillikan yes, but for the sake of this problem, I cannot evaluate sqrt(x) directly

Comment: You can plug in $90$ for $x$ but you don't know what $c$ is.  You can bound the error by finding the $c$ where the derivative is maximized but you won't know how much better it is.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your series expansion is not correct. The general expansion is
$$\sqrt x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty 10^{1-2 n} \binom{\frac{1}{2}}{n} (x-100)^n$$ and then
$$T_3(x)=10+\frac{(x-100)}{20}-\frac{(x-100)^2}{8000}+\frac{(x-100)^3}{1600000}+O\left((x-100)   ^4\right)$$
$$\big|\sqrt{x} - T_2(x) \big| = ???$$